# Filling user_id attribute of Reply model (attribute that isn't attr_accesible)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: `User`, `Post` and, `Reply`. An `user` has many `posts` and `comments`. A post had many `replies` and belongs to an `user`, and a `reply` belongs to a `post` and an `user`.

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :posts do
  resources :replies
end
```

**schema.rb:**

```
  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content",    :limit => 255
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
    t.string   "title"
  end

  create_table "replies", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

This is how I'm creating comments:

**comments_controller.rb:**

```
 def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @reply = @post.replies.build(params[:reply])
    if @reply.save!
      flash[:success] = "reply created!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end
  end
```

**replies/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.replies.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Enter reply content" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Reply", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

After submitting the form I get this error:

```
Validation failed: User can't be blank
```

I assume its because the reply's attribute `user_id` is empty:

**reply.rb**

```
validates :user_id, presence: true
```

I'm not sure how to fill that attribute. I can't just put it in `Reply` `attr_accesible`, because that would compromise the security of the app (as far as I know).

Any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_acessible` only affects things when you're updating/creating a record from a hash of attributes. You can always set an attribute by calling the accessor directly, so after you've built the reply,

```
@reply.user = current_user
```

Should do the trick (assuming you're using something like devise or authlogic that defined `current_user` for you. You could also assign to `@reply.user_id` directly.

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between using `@reply.user_id = current_user.id` and `@reply.user = current_user`? Which one is more recomendable?

Comment: The end result is the same (although i vaguely recall some edge cases if you try to use both at the same time). The only real difference is to do @reply.user= you need to have the user loaded, if you only have the id it can feel a little wasteful to load the user just for that